# One to One screensharing using WEBRTC

Tags: node.js, html, streaming, webrtc

Im developing a web application that lets users to share/access one users screen on the other, Im building it with webRTC, is it possible to do a one-to-one private sharing with webRTC? I have seen examples doing one to all videocam sharing, Im new to webRTC and not sure if there is a beginner tutorial to learn things better with this.

any sample would be more than great help!.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this which includes all the source: https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/Pluginfree-Screen-Sharing

Comment: @Mick: does it? I couldnt find the one to one sample anywhere, everywhere it is one to all- broadcasting

Comment: You would use 99% exactly the same code as setting up a one-to-one webcam webRTC session.  The only difference would be the parameters you pass into getUserMedia.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do screen sharing over WebRTC. [This](https://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/getusermedia/screenshare.html) is a good simple demo page for Chrome. You might get a `--enable-usermedia-screen-capture flag?` error. In that case try this [demo](https://mozilla.github.io/webrtc-landing/gum_test.html) on Firefox.

Also note that screen sharing is only possible if your webpage is accessed using **https**.